# jQuery selector performance for .is(), .delegate(), etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-selectors

When selecting elements with jQuery, I know that something like `input.foo` is faster than `.foo`, esp in IE. But what about when using `.is()`? It almost seems like it would be the reverse since there is less parsing to do of the `.foo` selector and fewer checks to make against the element in question. Am I correct about this? If I am, would the same logic apply to `.delegate()`?

Thanks,

Jim

Comment: Not sure I understand the correlation between `.is()` and `.delegate()`; one is a filter, the other is for binding events. For performance questions, I tend to run some tests on jsperf.com

Comment: Since with `.is()` and `.delegate()` there always is a context, I don't think that it matters in these cases. In both cases the selector isn't used to query anything but just to match the given element...

Comment: @GregPettit The selector passed to `.delegate()` is used when an event bubbles to the thing to which you delegated. The original target of the event is matched against (a.k.a. filtered) the selector (as you would with `.is()`) to see if the event handlers should run.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas well that's why I think it would be faster to avoid filtering with over-specificity when possible. Because nothing is actually being queried and you're simply trying to see if the element matches criteria, it seems the less criteria provided the faster it could check.

Comment: @JAAulde Yes, I expect less criteria to be faster, but insignificantly faster. The process in general (regardless of selector) is fast. In the case of `input.foo` vs. `.foo`, if you are certain that you hold INPUT elements, there is no reason to use the longer selector.